# AVPlayerView disappears when exiting full screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen, avplayer

On OS X (not iOS), I have an AVPlayerView in a window along with other controls. I am able to play it and have it go full screen with the button in the control bar. However, when I click the control bar to return to normal view (exiting full screen), the video and player disappear. The audio continues, but my view seems to have been lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was because I was setting the AVPlayerView as the contentView of an NSBox to make a "tab-like" interface. Using an NSTabView instead (without a border) works.